# Grails/Groovy : SQL.execute not inserting data in DB2 database but no errors in application log

Tags: java, sql, grails, groovy, cron

I am using below code to insert data into DB2 tables and it's part of a grails cron job. Job ran successfully but i don't see data inserted in Database tables. I don't see any errors also in application log. I reran the same job after some time and i see the data in database tables. I am not sure why i see this behaviour.

Code Snippet :

```
def conn = new Sql( dataSource )
For loop which is running from 1 to 11813
conn.execut("SQL Query")
```

Few things: 
1. I have not explicitly called conn.close() since when we are using SQL with datasource we don't have to call this
2. Method in which i am using this conn.execute is Transactional.
3. This method contains hibernate object save also and it is like below:

```
if (!Object.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)) {
                //throw exception
                }
```

Can you please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Not enough info to be able to tell what the problem might be, But if there are no dirty properties, grails won't save data to DB.

Comment: What info you need ?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide more code? Are you trying to update existing data or create new data? Since the method is transactional, there might be a chance that the transaction is being rolled back. Are you catching any exceptions and not logging it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code into a grails service and add the @Transactional annotation above the class name.